# DownloadManager - Rename download if file already exists

Tags: android, file, rename, exists

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

    Uri u = Uri.parse(url);
    File f = new File("" + u);

    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
    request.setTitle("");
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, f.getName());

    // just my bullshit here please correct here                    
    if (f.exists()) {
        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File from = new File(sdcard,f.getName());
        File to = new File(sdcard,"*"+f.getName());
        from.renameTo(to);
    }

    DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    manager.enqueue(request);

                    }
```

I have this little code then when clicked it download file from a url but when the file is already downloaded and have the same name it just show fail, how can I check if file already exist and let the DownloadManager download that file with different name?

Answer (score 1):

The `DownloadManager` renames files by default when they exist. It will append a `-[NUMBER]` at the end of the filename.

So `hello.jpg` is turned to `hello-1.jpg`.

Maybe have a look at [this example](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2011/06/14/android-downloadmanager-example/). I used it and it works.